# Will IBM's asshole test work?

Tags: interviewing, behavior, behavioral-interview

When I read this article about [IBM's asshole test](https://johnpublic.mataroa.blog/blog/the-asshole-test/), I doubt that will work.

> This is an asshole test. You see who turns into an asshole under
> pressure and they don't make it to the next round".

Of course it is important to find out who will freak out under pressure but I doubt you can find the person during the interview. For starters, most interviewee I experienced were a bit nervous, so to turn a nervous person into asshole on purpose?! I think that goes to far, there should be a better way to do that.

To make my question more objective do anyone know if IBM still uses this kind of test ?

Comment: Well.  I'll make a note to never apply to IBM... :/

Comment: Sadly folks here don't want to talk about it.

Comment: This isnt a chat forum, you need to word your question in a way that it will make it a useful resource for many and not something that will have an opinion based answer.  Have a look here (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit it, if you do and it gets enough moderator votes it can be reopened.

Comment: Actually I already felt I may get that, so I said in my question "do anyone know if IBM still uses this kind of test" ?  As for reopen, no I don't bother too.

Comment: I cant tag you directly because of the chinese characters but that format question still falls under "company specific policies" which makes it off topic.  You need to reword it so it is more generic.  Maybe try something like "do companies still use these, is there a way to recognise what the actual purpose of the test is and how can we perform better" - and as a side note you could mention IBM used to do it but you're not sure if they still do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but why bother for a closed question for 5 downvotes ? If I had not gotten an answer I would just delete my question.

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗: If you wish to delete the question, I could try deleting my answer. I've been in the same situation a few times, when I've wanted to delete a question, but couldn't because someone posted an answer. So I understand. The question actually got 6 downvotes. I upvoted :-)

Comment: @Nav thanks but let's just keep it here, I like your answer!

Comment: @solarflare FYI I just asked chatGPT about the test and it said "It's worth noting that IBM has not confirmed the existence of the "asshole test" and it is unclear whether the test is still in use or has been used recently by the company."

Comment: I like it how many interesting comments are there under that short article!

Comment: @red-shield well I was frustated that the question was closed and got 4 down-votes

Answer (score 2):

People don't always behave the same when undergoing a test of this kind under pressure, versus when under pressure in a real project, where the technical and social parameters are different.

Also, in a real project, the person would have past achievements (or mistakes) the team would know of, which can make even a rude person mellow.

The so called "asshole test" is just somebody's creative juices that got approval from someone else who didn't know what else to do differently while recruiting people.

Do have a look at the [Stanford Prison Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_prison_experiment) and [Milgram's Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment).

Comment: I was told that pilots in fake emergencies in a flight simulator act much worse than pilots in real world emergencies. Mostly because in the flight simulator they can only lose, and in real world they can become heroes. Same can happen interview vs. real work.